# Difference between IIS Smooth Streaming and Windows media Service

Tags: silverlight, smooth-streaming, windows-media-encoder, windows-media-server

I am looking in to options for windows streaming technologies for streaming live webcam  . I am not quite sure pros -cons , price and media format differences between the two . I know that IIS smooth streaming is newer technology and end user has to install silver light plugin to load video . What are other major differences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found there's quite a bit of confusing information out there due to similar terminology being used and regular releases making even slightly old blog posts out of date.

I assume your question is around `"Windows Media Services"` and `IIS Smooth Streaming`

`Windows Media Services` is a [standalone update for Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=20424) (I don't believe its available for Server 2012). On installation you use the Server Manager to add WMS as a new server role. WMS provides for on-demand streaming and live streaming, I dont believe it provides for `adaptive bitrate streaming`

`IIS Smooth Streaming` is available in IIS7 via this standalone update [IIS7 Media Services 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=27955). It is available in IIS8/Server 2012 without any additional download.
IIS Smooth streaming is Microsoft's product name for 'on-demand' smooth streaming.

This is a good blog post [explaining IIS smooth streaming](http://brandonpotter.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/demystifying-iis-smooth-streaming-live-smooth-streaming/).

Pricing - they are both free, assuming you already have the OS licence.